# Who rescues Davidge in 'Enemy Mine'?

Tags: movie, enemy-mine

In the Dennis Quaid adaptation of [Enemy Mine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_Mine_%28film%29), who rescues Davidge from Fyrine IV? Are the rescuers aware of the scavenger ship? Why do three other pilots (I don't recall if they were the same ones in the opening battle of the movie) claim to have taken a risk to rescue him? (I sense a missing sequence here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I watched the movie just yesterday by chance.

The movie doesn't say much about the ship that found him. In fact, his whole rescue is kind of strange. After three years he's suddenly found right when he's about to die. I don't recall any mention of a tracker or emergency beacon. So how did they even find him lying on a desert-like planet in the middle of nowhere? It's possible they came to investigate the earlier weapons discharge or just flew over the planet and found weak life signs or some such thing. But all in all I can't remember a good explanation. He apparently was just lucky.

It's also possible that they were checking on the Scavenger ship but they were most likely not pursuing them. Earlier in the movie, Davidge says that the Scavengers are tolerated despite or even because they use Drac as slave labor. So apparently no law enforcement cares about them. Also, why would their ship be at the very same place again, if they were hunted by law enforcement or military?

As for his friend, I think what he meant when he said that they took a risk was that they put in a good word for him. After all, he was speaking Drac in delirium which is why they thought he might be a Drac spy. They also wondered where he was the past three years. If he was really stranded or had worked with the Drac.

His friends however, said something along the lines of, "No way, he's Davidge, he's one of us". If there was an investigation on Davidge, they would have looked into his friends too, to try and find out if they were spies too and if they tried to cover for him because he slipped up.

I actually thought there was a scene like that in the movie, but there wasn't. Maybe it's in some sort of extended cut or I just got it wrong.

**Edit:** Did some more digging and also rewatched the rescue scene. Davidge says in his monologue that he was picked up by a surveillance team. No information other then that on his rescue. It's pretty vague.

I also found a German website which compares the DVD version with some other cut that aired on German TV. There are apparently some scenes missing/cut in the DVD version or at least some versions.

The 2 most notable have to do with the time after his rescue. One is in the infirmary where they patch up Davidge. The guy who says he might have worked for the enemy is apparently a security officer. The female pilot speaks up for Davidge and asks them to at least wait until he has recovered. To which they agree. This must be what the other pilot means when he says, that they stuck out their necks for him. This second part of the scene is missing in the version I recently watched.

The second scene involves the other pilots telling Davidge to forget about what happened and to give up on getting back to that planet. Davidge gets angry and storms off. This is directly before the scene in the corridor where one of the pilots again tries to stop him. This is also missing from said version.

This must be the cut I remembered from seeing it years ago on German TV.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Your explanation for the actions of his friends makes sense. This movie could really use a remake (retaining Maurice Jarre though).

Comment: @coleopterist Edited my answer with some new information.

Answer (score 0):

if I remember correctly they were pursuing the outlaw ship

but Id have to watch the movie again to see if theres any explicit reference